# Pyspark date_trunc without modifying actual value

Tags: pyspark

Consider the below dataframe

df:

| time |
| --- |
| 2022-02-21T11:23:54 |

I have to convert it to

| time |
| --- |
| 2022-02-21T11:23:00 |

After using the below code

`df.withColumn("time_updated", date_trunc("minute", col("time"))).show(truncate = False)`

My output

| time |
| --- |
| 2022-02-21 11:23:00 |

By desired output is

| time |
| --- |
| 2022-02-21T11:23:00 |

Is there anyway I can keep the data same and just update/truncate the seconds??

Comment: `2022-02-21T11:23:54` is not a date, it is the string representation of a timestamp. What is the schema of the column ? You are probably converting from string to date somewhere. You simply have to format it back to the original format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply have a format issue. the output that you see is the string representation of a timestamp. check your output formats :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W, types as T

df = df.withColumn(
    "time_updated",
    F.date_format(F.col("time").cast("timestamp"), "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:00"),
)

df.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------+-------------------+                                       
|time               |time_updated       |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2022-02-21T11:23:54|2022-02-21T11:23:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time_updated: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what does "F" represents here??

Comment: @userunknown added imports